# Wifi unstable in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, windows-10

I have a dual-boot system with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a problem with my Wi-Fi , the Wi-Fi is connected to the router but the internet stops working intermittently and unable to load anything.  Also some times there is a question mark in the Wi-Fi symbol. After I try

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

the internet works for 2-3 seconds and then again it says no internet in the browser but I am always connected to Wi-Fi and in range.
Output of command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`is

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

Asus X55C
(Wifi is working properly in Win10)
Thankyou

Comment: Could you update your question to include the brand and model of your computer? This will make it much easier to offer more specific assistance. 

Comment: Is it ok now?@Matigo

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Is it ok now ? @Pilot6

Comment: It is OK now, but I am afraid nothing can be done with this Ralink adapter. It is poorly supported by Linux.

Comment: So according to my observations the sites fedback is like www.examplesite.com DNS server address cannot be found. The internet is ok for 1-2 hour but after it fluctuates is it there any command to reset network manager? Btw Thankyou @Pilot6

Comment: You can reset Network Manager by `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` but I don't thing it will help.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Am I supposed to do this command in terminal @waltinator

Comment: So what if I set ipv4 and ipv6 according to my router settings manually and how to find correct gateway and netmask,etc?@Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I searched many posts and founded a post in which he said to try this command in terminal
`sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*`  and restarted network manager by using command `sudo service network-manager restart` after disabling ipv6 and this worked .